# What is the syntax for rendering a value into a Pug/Jade comment?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to output some diagnostic information into my page in a comment. Is there a way to render a value into a comment in Pug/Jade?

I've tried

```
// MY_VALUE
// #{MY_VALUE}
// !{MY_VALUE}

//
    MY_VALUE
```

There is one method that works:

```
script /* #{MY_VALUE} */
```

but that renders a full script block onto the page.

Is there a syntax that will allow rendering a value into a comment in a Pug template?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the (arguably more verbose) HTML comment syntax:

```
<!-- #{MY_VALUE} -->
```

This works, because Pug accepts plain HTML syntax, too. See [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/EogJaK) for a demonstration: Try inspecting the Codepen output in your browser inspection tool to see that the interpolated part in the code is indeed evaluated.